# what is the relation between facebook id and location?

Tags: facebook, location

what is the relation between the facebook ID and location ? can I know someone's country using his facebook ID ? 
pretty thanks for the one who inform .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get someone´s country by [authorizing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2) a Facebook user with the `user_location` permission. After that, the location should be in the response of the [/me](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user) endpoint. You can test this in the API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.2